# How can I prove that Xn converges to 0 in distribution?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

Xn~U[-1/n,1/n]. Since for convergence in distribution  Xn-->X iff Fn(x)-->F(x). First of all, I am trying to get the cumulative  and it is Fn(x)=(1+xn)/2. Hence, [image]
am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Surely $$F_n(x)=\frac{nx+1}{2}$$ but this is only true for $x \in \left[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right]$ which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. In particular $$F_n(x)=\begin{cases}0, &x<-\frac{1}{n}\\\frac{nx+1}{2}, &-\frac{1}{n}\le x \le \frac{1}{n}\\ 1, &\frac{1}{n}<x \end{cases}$$ from which you can see that the formula you have above is only valid for the interval $[-1/n, 1/n]$, which converges to the point $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Isn´t it supposed to be 0 for all intervals?

Comment: No, the sequence converges to a degenerate random variable, that takes value 0 with probability 1. So indeed the random variable X is always 0. Thus F(x)=0 for all x<0 but F(x)=1 for all $x\ge 0$. Surely the random variable X is always 0. But the distribution function has to take also the value 1. Do you get it?

Comment: Once again, thank you, but I am getting 1/2 when x=0, isn´t it supposed to be 1 as when x>0?

Comment: No, you do not get 1/2, that is false. As n goes to infinity, x goes to zero, so nx is indefinite form, do not forget that. Divide with n denominator and numerator to see that it goes to x indeed, as you already had it. But x goes to zero... do not get confused

Comment: My apologies, I don´t know if there is something I am missing here, but this is what I got: $$lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{nx+1}{2} = lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x+\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{2}{n}}=\frac{x+\frac{1}{\infty}}{\frac{2}{\infty}}= \frac{x+0}{0}=\frac{x}{0}=\infty$$

Comment: But $x$ goes also to zero, because it is in the interval [-1/n, 1/n] which vanishes. Sorre, there is no other way to explain it...